# How do I utilize the TPT FileName attribute to list multiple files?

Tags: teradata, bulk-load

The documentation of Teradata's `tbuild` bulk utility states that I can list multiple files if I set `FileList = 'Y'`. It does not, however, mention *how* to do so.

[image: Teradata Docs]

I have tried something similar to this:

```
VARCHAR FileList = 'YES',
VARCHAR FileName        = '\\path\to\file\file1.csv',
'\\path\to\file\file2.csv',
'\\path\to\file\file3.csv',
'\\path\to\file\file4.csv'
```

Which fails with this error (one for each file). This is the same error that occurs if I attempt to surround the entire thing with parenthesis:

```
TPT_INFRA: Syntax error at or near line 30 of Job Script File 'File_list_test.sql':
TPT_INFRA: At "\\path\to\file\file1.csv" missing { ARRAY_ BIGINT_ BYTEINT_ CHARACTER_ CHAR_ CHARACTERS_ CHARS_ INT_ INTEGER_ LONG_ SMALLINT_ VARCHAR_ VARDATE_ REGULAR_IDENTIFIER_ EXTENDED_IDENTIFIER_ EXTENDED_IDENTIFIER_NO_N_ } in Rule: Attribute Definition
```

I've tried to surround the entire list in double quotes. That fails with this error:

```
TPT_INFRA: At "'\\path\to\file\file1.csv','\\path\to\file\file2.csv','\\path\to\file\file3.csv','\\path\to\file\file4.csv'" missing { PLUS_ MINUS_ JOB_ATTRIBUTE_REFERENCE_ EXTENDED_LITERAL_ CHAR_STRING_LITERAL_ UNSIGNED_INTEGER_ EXACT_NUMERIC_VALUE_ APPROX_NUMERIC_VALUE_ } in Rule: Initial Value
```

I've tried to surround the entire list with square brackets which fails with this error:

```
TPT_INFRA: At "VARCHAR" missing RPAREN_ in Rule: Attribute List Definition
```

I've also tried to set `VARCHAR FileName =` to each file. Predictably, that fails with this error:

```
TPT_INFRA: TPT03044: Attribute 'FileName' is already on Operator 'My_DataConnector_Test' attribute list.
Duplicate definition is rejected.
```

How do I provide a file list so that I can load selected files via the `tbuild` utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a few years ago when I tried FileList the first time :-)

You just have to read the manuals carefully:

> the **file** specified by *FileName* contains a list of files to be
>   processed.
>
> When used with the FileList attribute, *fileName* **is expected to
>   contain a list of names** of the files to be processed, each with a full
>   path specification

The file specified by *FileName* must be a text file with each file name on a new line.

This is the content of the file "myfile.txt":

```
\\path\to\file\file1.csv
\\path\to\file\file2.csv
\\path\to\file\file3.csv
\\path\to\file\file4.csv
```

And now "myfile.txt" is the file used in TPT:

```
VARCHAR FileList = 'YES',
VARCHAR FileName = 'myfile.txt'
```